# Multiplying variables

Tags: javascript, variables

Hi I'm just confused about how to set a variable to that variable multiplied by it's self. After a lot of looking on the internet an trying different things I still couldn't get it to work even though it feels like it should be working. Here's the script...

```js
var totalSmalls = (totalSmalls*smallPrice);
var totalMediums = (totalMediums*mediumPrice);
var totalLarges = (totalLarges*largePrice);
var totalNumber = totalsmalls + totalMediums + totalLarges;
```

the variables were all working as far as I could tell. I'll attach the full program as well...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>PizzaLife</title>
<script>
 
var smallPrice = 3.50;
var mediumPrice = 5.00;
var largePrice = 9.99;
var totalSmalls = 0;
var totalMediums = 0;
var totalLarges = 0;
var totalNumber = 0;

function calculateOrder()//calculate the number of smalls, larges and medium pizzas
{
var pizza = new Array()
var smallPizza = new Array()
smallPizza[0] = Number(document.form.smallP.value)
smallPizza[1] = Number(document.form.smallC.value)
smallPizza[2] = Number(document.form.small4.value)
smallPizza[3] = Number(document.form.smallT.value)
smallPizza[4] = Number(document.form.smallM.value)

var mediumPizza = new Array()
mediumPizza[5] = Number(document.form.mediumP.value)
mediumPizza[6] = Number(document.form.mediumC.value)
mediumPizza[7] = Number(document.form.medium4.value)
mediumPizza[8] = Number(document.form.mediumT.value)
mediumPizza[9] = Number(document.form.mediumM.value)

var largePizza = new Array()
largePizza[10] = Number(document.form.largeP.value)
largePizza[11] = Number(document.form.largeC.value)
largePizza[12] = Number(document.form.large4.value)
largePizza[13] = Number(document.form.largeT.value)
largePizza[14] = Number(document.form.largeM.value)

totalSmalls = smallPizza[0] + smallPizza[1] + smallPizza[2] + smallPizza[3] + smallPizza[4];
totalMediums = mediumPizza[5] + mediumPizza[6] + mediumPizza[7] + mediumPizza[8] + mediumPizza[9];
totalLarges = largePizza[10] + largePizza[11] + largePizza[12] + largePizza[13] + largePizza[14];

alert ("you have ordered " + totalSmalls + " Small pizzas " + totalMediums + " Mediums and " + totalLarges + " Larges." );
var totalSmalls = (totalSmalls*smallPrice);
var totalMediums = (totalMediums*mediumPrice);
var totalLarges = (totalLarges*largePrice);
var totalNumber = totalsmalls + totalMediums + totalLarges;
alert ("Your order will cost a total of $" + totalNumber + "yaaz");
}

function resetOrder() //to reset the page and order
{
if (confirm ("Are you sure you want to reset the order?") == true)
{
window.location.reload()
}
}

</script>
<body>
<p><font face = "jokerman" size="10" color="DarkGreen"><b>PizzaLife  NZ</b></font>
<font face="jokerman" size="6" color="DarkGreen"><i>  Online</i></font></p>
 
<p><font face = "Arial Black" size = "2">Use the arrows to take your pick of our pizzas!</font><br>

<i>note: max per order is 99 pizzas</i></p>
<p>Large Pizza: $9.99 <br>Medium Pizza: $5.00 <br>Small Pizza: $3.50</p>

<form name = "form">
<font face = "Arial Black" size = "2">
<font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">Pepperoni Pizza: </font><br>
Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "largeP"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "mediumP"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "smallP"><br>
<font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">Cheesy Pizza: </font><br>
Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "largeC"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "mediumC"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "smallC"><br>
<font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">4Meats Pizza: </font><br>
Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "large4"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "medium4"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "small4"><br>
<font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">TooHot Pizza: </font><br>
Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "largeT"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "mediumT"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "smallT"><br>
<font face = "Arial Black" size = "2" color = "red">minceNcheese Pizza: </font><br>
Larges:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "largeM"> Mediums:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "mediumM"> smalls:<input type = "number" min = "0" max = "99" name = "smallM"><br>
</font>
</form>

<p>
---------------------&lsaquo;<input type = "button" value = "reset" onclick = "resetOrder()"><input type = "button" value = "Get Em!" onclick = "calculateOrder()">&rsaquo;------------------------
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"how to set a variable to that variable multiplied by it's self"* - I can't see anywhere in your code where you try to multiply a variable by itself. But `x=x*x` or `x*=x` is all you need.

Comment: You only use var to declare a variable. Once declared do not use var. To Multiply by its self. First declare it `var num = 100` then you can `num *= num` same as num = num * num` you can do the same with += -= \= and a few more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `var` from this line:

```
var totalSmalls = (totalSmalls*smallPrice);
```

And from the other similar lines, to get this:

```
totalSmalls = (totalSmalls*smallPrice);
totalMediums = (totalMediums*mediumPrice);
totalLarges = (totalLarges*largePrice);
totalNumber = totalSmalls + totalMediums + totalLarges;
```

You are trying to update the global variables that are declared at the top of your script, but then by using `var` inside your function you've created local variables of the same names. That's not actually a syntax error, but if you wanted the variables to be global then the code wouldn't work as intended.

What would cause a runtime error is in that fourth line you had a lower case "s" in `totalSmalls`.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot I don't know how I didn't know that :D

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your second alert does not work is because you have a typo in this line:

```
var totalNumber = totalsmalls + totalMediums + totalLarges;
```

It should be capital letter in `totalSmalls`

```
var totalNumber = totalSmalls + totalMediums + totalLarges;
```

And yes, you need to remove var keyword from every size total. You are redeclaring it and when browser reads your javascript it replaces one variable with a whole new one.

Comment: Thanks, As you can probably tell I'm Just learning html so I make heaps of simple errors and can't figure out how to fix them :D

Comment: No problem! It took some time for every one to learn! Don't forget to mark your question as answered and good luck!